# How Skip at Last Frame using Button in flash

Tags: flash, goto

I need to go to the Last frame when I click on my button.

I use following code

```
on (release) {
gotoAndPlay(1530);
}
```

I also try on (click) method But when I click or release on button it reacts like refreshing my current flash page. can Any I help me out.
My last frame page number is 1530.

I also tried

```
on (release) {
    gotoAndPlay(1174);
    }
```

which is not the last frame, still it shows the my first frame..

Can anybody help out..!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay in your last frame of a movieclip which is added in the stage then you should add the following snippet to your button, like,

```
on (release) {
    _root.myMovie.gotoAndStop(1530);
}
```

Note: Assumed `myMovie` is the instance name of your movieclip placed in the stage.

Comment: you have the above snippet on the movieclip you want to go to the last frame, right?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, It still saws me refreshed page. I want to Play my frame.